# Not sure why I'm getting a NaN returning - Inside fn() it works - outside it does not

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out why I'm getting an NaN return and undefined in the below case.

Variables total, tip, numPeople are all numbers and give me the correct value when console.log.

Variable Score is giving me the problem and returns NaN and undefined.  But when I put it into a function and call it variable Score2 I get the correct result and everything works fine?

```
typeof(total) // Returns Number & console.log gives me the value
typeof(tip) // Returns Number & console.log gives me the value
typeof(numPeople) // Returns Number & console.log gives me the value

let score = total * tip /  numPeople; 
typeof(score) // This returns "number" as I would expect
console.log(score) // This returns NaN and undefined?? WHY? 

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let score2 = total * tip /  numPeople; // Returns CORRECT
    alert(`The individual tip is $${score2.toFixed(2)}`);
})
```

I do not understand why Score returns NaN and Score2 returns the CORRECT number value and works correctly? Thank you for any thoughts

Comment: What are the **exact** values of `total`, `tip` and `numPeople`? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: One of JavaScript's quirks is that typeof not-a-number is... number.

Comment: Use `isNaN(...)` to check if a number is actually `NaN`. If you execute `typeof(NaN)` you'll get `number`

Comment: Make sure that total, tip, and numPeople has value assigned.

Comment: Might be a problem with asynchronicity.

Comment: I have run the above code, and getting the correct output for score.
```
var total = 1;
var tip = 2;
var numPeople = 3;
typeof(total) // Returns Number & console.log gives me the value
typeof(tip) // Returns Number & console.log gives me the value
typeof(numPeople) // Returns Number & console.log gives me the value

let score = total * tip /  numPeople; 
typeof(score) // This returns "number" as I would expect
console.log(score);
```